# iOS: What is happening when I call a overridden method from other class

Tags: objective-c

I have a superclass named `Card` which has a method:

```
-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards{
    return 0;
}
```

Then I override this method in subclass named `PlayingCard`

```
-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards{
    int score = 0;
    if ([otherCards count]==1) {
        PlayingCard *otherCard = [otherCards firstObject];
        if (otherCard.rank==self.rank) {
            score=4;
        }else if ([otherCard.suit isEqualToString:self.suit]){
            score=1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

But when I call the overridden method from other class like this

```
Card *card=[self cardAtIndex:index];
self.matchScore=[card match:@[otherCard]];
```

Why it implements the method the one I override in subclass? I think that the matchScore should always be 0, but it doesn't. I think it should implement the method in superclass, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: What does `cardAtIndex:` really return? An instance of a `Card` object or an instance of a `PlayingCard` object?

Comment: It returns a `self.cards[index]` which has a `Card` object in it.

Comment: If the overloaded `match:` method from `PlayingCard` is being called then `cardAtIndex:` is returning a `PlayingCard` instance, not a `Card` instance. Perhaps you should update your question with some relevant code showing how you populate your `cards` array.

Comment: Thanks, I use the introspection to justify that it is a `PlayingCard` object.And I realize I did put a `PlayingCard` object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods in Objective-C are virtual. That means, called `match:` implementation depends on `card` class. So, if `[self cardAtIndex:index]` return `PlayingCard` instance, `-[PlayingCard match:]` would be called. It's exactly what happens in your case.

Note that declaring `Card *card`, as well as casting to superclass, will not affect `card` class in runtime. It only provides additional information to compiler to detect some dumb errors in build time.

Comment: That's my issue. Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that it returns a `PlayingCard` instance, so I use `Card *`.

Comment: @NeoZ Another point of clarity;  casting will not change what method is invoked.  The casting is only for the compiler's benefit, it won't change runtime behavior.  (This is oft a point of confusion for some.)

Comment: @bbum, thanks, I've updated my answer. For me this point looked obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Following can be the reason

```
[self cardAtIndex:index];
```

This method returns you object of PlayigCard class and not object of Card. 
hence the object calls implementation of its own class and not of super class

you can verify by writing this

```
if ([card isKindOfClass:[PlayingCard class]) {
      NSLog(@"It's Playing Card not Card");
}
```